# i want to fit a model in sklearn but it throws an error. below are the lines of code i used

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, data-science, data-analysis

I used the lines of code below to fit a model in sklearn.

```
linearmodel =LinearRegression()
linearmodel.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

but I get this error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'

what could be wrong?

Comment: post all the code and data. the error says it all!!!! `y_train` should not be "male" "female" but numbers.

Comment: You should use some type of an Encoder to map string representation into numbers. Take a look at LabelEncoder (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `y_train` contains Strings, they should be numbers associated to a class.

Eg : 0 for Male, 1 for Female etc

After you get the prediction out after training, you have to display the class label associated to the number.

Comment: thank you, your comment helped me in solving the problem

Comment: Glad that was of help. Please mark this answer as Accepted so the question can be closed.